# Vue.js, vue-cli 3.0 and Google Webfonts

Tags: vue.js, webfonts, google-webfonts, vue-cli

I'm COMPLETLY LOST about including Google Fonts into my project.

I've installed google-fonts-webpack-plugin and tried to configure it properly, but the html is not being injected. Or maybe I'm not thinking about it right. Regardless, how to I include Google Webfonts?

Code in my vue.config.js:

```
const GoogleFontsPlugin = require("google-fonts-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
 configureWebpack: {
  plugins: [
    new google-fonts-webpack-plugin({
      fonts: [
          { family: "IBM Plex Sans" }
      ]
    })
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: When I try it out, I run into this issue ~ https://github.com/gabiseabra/google-fonts-webpack-plugin/issues/24

Answer (score 3):

Go to the end of app.vue and add below code:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is not currently compatible with the version of Webpack used by vue-cli.

What I've usually done in the past is just include the fonts via `<link>` tags in the `index.html` file, eg

```html
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
<title>vue</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

You could also edit the `<style>` block in your `App.vue` component to include

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans");
```